# Django: filtering queryset by date doesn´t apply any filter at all

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I´m trying to filter a queryset by the dates.

First I group the data by dates and have no problem.

```
inventario_original = Inventario.objects.all()
inventario = inventario_original.values("fecha").annotate(
    valor_coste=Sum(F('existencias') * F('valor_coste')),
    valor_venta=Sum(F('existencias') * F('valor_venta')),
    existencias=Sum('existencias'))
```

Then i find the last date in the queryset.

```
ultima_fecha_cargada = inventario_original.order_by('-fecha')
ultima_fecha_cargada = ultima_fecha_cargada.first().values('fecha')
```

If I print `ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha` I get `['15-03-2019']`

Finaly I want to filter the queryset with items with that last date.

```
inventario_producto = inventario_original.filter(fecha__date=ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha).values("codigo_kinemed").annotate(existencias=Sum('existencias'))
```

I get the full queryset with no filter applied. If I print the resulting dates I get `['15-03-2019']`so the date format matches.

Also tried

```
filter(fecha=ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha)
filter(fecha=ultima_fecha_cargada)
filter(fecha=date(day=15, month=3, year=2019))
filter(fecha__contains=ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha)
filter(fecha__contains=date(day=15, month=3, year=2019)
```

**The full view code here**

```
def InventarioView(request):
    inventario_original = Inventario.objects.all()
    ultima_fecha_cargada = inventario_original.order_by('-fecha')
    ultima_fecha_cargada = ultima_fecha_cargada.first().values('fecha')

    inventario = inventario_original.values("fecha").annotate(
        valor_coste=Sum(F('existencias') * F('valor_coste')),
        valor_venta=Sum(F('existencias') * F('valor_venta')),
        existencias=Sum('existencias'))

    inventario_producto = inventario_original.filter(fecha__date=ultima_fecha_cargada).values("codigo_kinemed").annotate(
        existencias=Sum('existencias'))

    return render(request, 'catalog/inventario.html', {
        'ultima_fecha_cargada': ultima_fecha_cargada,
        'inventario_producto': inventario_producto,
        'inventario': inventario,
    })
```

Comment: The code you say you have run has several syntax errors; please post the code that you have actually run.

Comment: @EndreBoth just added it to the question

Comment: This code cannot run, it is syntactically wrong: `ultima_fecha_cargada = ultima_fecha_cargada.first().values('fecha')`. Didn't get a syntax error when running the view?

Comment: @EndreBoth Not only I didn´t get an error, it works and I can print `ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha` in the template and get the correct date.

Comment: 1) `QuerySet.first()` returns a single object that doesn't have a `values('index')` method. 2) `Queryset.values()` returns a QuerySet of dictionaries whose entries you cannot access with the dot operator. So I'm afraid we cannot even begin to help when you seem to work in a different language :).

Comment: I restarted the computer and now I do get an error with the .values().

Answer (score 0):

As @Endre Both remarked, my code was not right. This was the correct code (without the values).

```
ultima_fecha_cargada = ultima_fecha_cargada.first()
```

And then this to filter by date.

```
inventario_producto = inventario_original.filter(fecha=ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha)
```

Now it works. The strange thing is that before I was able to see the results of using `ultima_fecha_cargada.first().values("fecha")`, got the expected value, printed it out correctly and had no error messages.

Now after a pc restart I started getting the error messages and the code seems to behave as Endre Both stated.